# stem puller for shower

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet

I've an old shower in my house that was leaking when I moved in 8 years ago. I removed the faucet and, for 7 years now, I've not been able to remove the stem. (yes, that's a long time, but kids got in the way :) ).

I just purchased a Moen stem puller (not sure of the make\model of the stem), but it was unable to thread in so I could pull the stem out.

Ideas?

Thank you

Comment: 7 years is about 6-3/4 years past the "time to rip the wall open and replace that thing" date, IMHO. i.e. longneck's option 2.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Find a screw that does fit the thread. You have the screw that holds the handle on, right? Take that screw to the hardware store and buy one that is threaded the same and 3-4 inches long. You can then drill a hole in a 2x4 for the screw (you'll probably need a washer) and use that 2x4 to pull the stem out.
2. Forget about changing the cartridge. Just open the back side of the wall and replace the whole assembly. If you have copper pipes, Shark-bite connectors make this a super easy fix nowadays.